# Variables nombre dinámico en PHP

Tags: php, matrices

Estaba creando dos matrices de 3x3 en PHP con el siguiente código:

```
        $matriz=array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$numeroFilas; $i++){
        for ($j=0; $j<$numeroColumnas; $j++){
            $matriz[$i][$j]=rand(1,10); 
        }       
    }
        print_r($matriz);

        echo "<br><br>";
        $matriz1=array();

    for ($i=0; $i<$numeroFilas; $i++){
        for ($j=0; $j<$numeroColumnas; $j++){
            $matriz1[$i][$j]=rand(1,10);    
        }       
    }
        print_r($matriz1);

        echo "<br><br>";
```

Pero me ha surgido la duda. ¿Si tuviese que crear 20 matrices tendría que poner el código 20 veces? No tiene sentido. Así que he intentado hacer una variable con nombre dinámico y meterla en un bucle para que me vaya haciendo tantas matrices de 3x3 como quiera, pero no consigo.

¿Cómo debería poner un nombre dinámico para poder hacerlo? Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres hacer 20 matrices de 3x3, es cómo hacer una matriz de 20x3x3... Podrías añadir otro índice, y otro bucle para ese otro nuevo índice... Sería como hacer un array de 20 elementos, los cuales son matrices de 3x3

Comment: Que tal una función? sería de gran utilidad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En PHP existen las [variables variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php), en donde después de el símbolo de variable `$` el nombre de la variable se expresa con otra variable o con una expresión, que puede ser de cadena según la reglas de [análisis de variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), las cuales te brindan varias opciones; algunos ejemplos:

```
for( $i=1; $i<=20; $i++ ){
   // Sintaxis simple:
   $nombre = 'matriz'.$i;
   $$nombre = array();
   
   // Sintaxis compleja:
   $prefijo = 'matriz';
   ${"$prefijo$i"} = array();
   ${"matriz$i"} = array();
   ${$prefijo.$i} = array();
}
// En este punto tienes disponibles desde $matriz1 hasta $matriz20
```

Comment: Esta es la mejor respuesta, sin embargo puede llegar a ser una muy mala practica de programación y restar escalabilidad, ya que la creación / definición de variables queda muy abstraída. 
En su lugar, lo mejor seria replantear la lógica y crear una estructura de datos ad hoc al problema.
Aún así, es una buena alternativa para acceder dinámicamente a una variable.